# SVG filter feGaussianBlur in not working properly IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm using `SVG` element of `HTML5` and it's working on Firefox, Chrome and safari but it's create problem on IE11 you can see the screenshot I attached.

[image]
[image]

On IE11 browser you can see the sharp edge upper side of puzzles area on other browsers it's smooth.

you can check the code on below mentioned link:
https://jsfiddle.net/agsyhzc1/2/

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It is should be supported [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters), but i had simmilar problem, took me a long time to sort it out kinda, I used https://modernizr.com/ to check if svg property was supported if not I ended up doing a fallback with transparent PNG as overlay. It is hack but it is the only solution i came up with. It is relevant for older IE I think that Edge